# counting tuples in $\mathbb Z^{i}$

Tags: combinatorics

Let $d$ be a positive integer, let $\mathbb N$ denote $\{1,2,\dots\}$. What is the size of the following subset of $\mathbb Z^{i}$?

$$
\{ (a_1, \dots, a_i) : a_j \in \mathbb N, \text{ and } a_1 + \dots + a_i \leq d \}.
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we should talk about the number of tuples with $a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_i = d$.
This is a well-known problem; it is the number of ordered partitions of $d$ into $i$ parts, and it is given by ${d-1} \choose {i-1}$.  You should be able to find extensive explanation of of this fact here on mathSE.

To get the number of tuples with $a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_i \le d$, we should just add up the number of tuples with $a_1 + \cdots + a_i = k$ for $k = i$ to $k = d$.  That is, we should compute
$$
\sum_{k = i}^{d} {{k-1} \choose {i-1}}
$$
which evaluates to ${d} \choose {i}$ by the [hockey-stick identity](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Combinatorial_identity).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of summing the solutions to $a_1+\cdots+a_i=k$ (or $k=i$) to $d$, you may find it easier to argue like this. Add a dummy variable $a_{i+1}$ restricted to the same set as the other variables. Then the number of solutions to $a_1+\cdots+a_i\le d$ is the same as the number of solutions to $a_1+\cdots+a_i+a_{i+1}=d+1$, i.e. $$\binom{d}{i}.$$